# Node.js promises using Q

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have a Node app that I'm writing where I need to use promises for async calls.

I currently have a foreach loop being called from within a .then(function()) of a promise, but when I return the end result of the foreach, I get nothing.

In the foreach I can console.log the value of data and retrieve it, but not outside the for loop before the return?

```
var Feeds = function(){
    this.reddit = new Reddit();
}

Feeds.prototype.parseRedditData = function(){
    var _this      = this;

    this.getData(this.reddit.endpoint).then(function(data){
        return _this.reddit.parseData(data, q);
    });
}

Feeds.prototype.getData = function(endpoint){
    var deferred = q.defer();

    https.get(endpoint, function(res) {
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
           deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        deferred.reject(e);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

var Reddit = function(){
    this.endpoint = "https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/hot.json?limit=10";
}

Reddit.prototype.parseData = function(json, q){
    var dataLength  = json.data.children.length,
        data        = [];

    for(var i = 0; i <= dataLength; i++){
        var post    = {};

        post.url    = json.data.children[i].data.url;
        post.title  = json.data.children[i].data.title;
        post.score  = json.data.children[i].data.score;

        data.push(post);
    }


    return data;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the use of Q's `.then` function or `forEach` anywhere in the code?

Comment: Q: Are you using the "--harmony" flag when you invoke Node.js?  Q: Do you have any error handlers (or any kind of error checking at all)?

Comment: Where is `this.getData`?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum updated with `this.getData`. Not passing any `--harmony`` flag in.

Comment: @JacobClark you're missing a `return` before `this.getData` in `parseRedditData`.

Comment: Even when I console.log within parseData after the for loop, I get undefined on my data variable.

Answer (score -1):

```
Feeds.prototype.parseRedditData = function(){
    var _this      = this;

    this.getData(this.reddit.endpoint).then(function(data){
        return _this.reddit.parseData(data, q);
    });
}
```

When i see this I see a "return" in the callback of the promise... I don't know why you're doing this, but I just want to be sure:

I you want this "return" to be the returned value of the function 'parseRedditData', this won't work.

The only way to return your data here is by using a callback, or a promise, like this:

```
Feeds.prototype.parseRedditData = function(callack){
    var _this      = this;

    this.getData(this.reddit.endpoint).then(function(data){
        callback(_this.reddit.parseData(data, q));
    });
}
```